# Angular-cli bootstrap v3 and jquery? Angular 2.0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular, angular-cli

So I am about to start a project and I think Angular 2.0 seems a very solid framework to work with: Routing, components, directives, etc.
However, there are many stuff already built using bootstrap v3 and jQuery that I would like to use.
I was wondering if it is possible to integrate bootstrap v3 and JQuery using the structure made by Angular-cli?

By the way I've seen other Angular 2 seeds using Gulp, but they always recommend the official Angular-cli instead.

Also I am new on how brining an existing JS library into Typescript actually works and if jquery's $ global will interfere with typescript.

Note: I am aware of ng2-bootstrap, but I don't think that everything is compatible with this approach since it doesn't use jquery as dependency.
I am also aware that using jquery in angular is not the best practice, but I think there are some cases in which you really need it for plugins or dependencies.

Comment: Did you try this one? https://github.com/jamesemann/ng2-vscode-template

Answer (score 6):

I can suggest you a workaround until they get better support for 3rd party libs. It worked for me :)

After typing

```
npm install jquery
```

and

```
 typings install jquery --ambient --save
```

In your angular-cli-build.json , make sure it remains like this way

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...
      'jquery/**/*.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

and in your system-config.ts:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
 const map: any = {
   'jquery': 'vendor/jquery'
 };
```

in your src/index.html add this line

```
<script src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

now in your component where you want to use jquery , write this way

```
declare var $:any;

@Component({
})
export class YourComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    $.("button").click(function(){
       // now you can DO, what ever you want 
     });
     console.log();
  }
}
```

I am doing it this way, in my project. Hope It might help you :) .

Comment: for me it stops at your 

`typings install jquery --ambient --save`

it just throws the following error:

` Unable to find "jquery" ("npm") in the registry. Did you want to try searching another source?`

I googled it but couldn't find anything interesting. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have your typings install globally ?

Comment: yes i do. But thanks for the noob security effort ;)

Comment: `npm install jquery --save ` then try again

Comment: still the same. maybe it's because I'm using jquery 2.2.4 instead of the latest 3.0.0 version?

Comment: It is nothing to do with version3 or version2, I am using jquery 2.2.4 in my project , Can you continue the process without this specific command

Comment: yes. I can include the scripts the way it is descripted but I dont seem to get the reason why i need to include it into the map in the system-config.ts

thanks for your effort so far :)

Comment: If we dont include it to map, it wont transfer the folder in the dist/vendor . It is a workaround which worked for me. I will follow this way until they get better support for 3rd party libs. Did you manage to run code with jquery ? I wish I could have some upvotes for this answers :P

Comment: I like your solution and it also works for bootstrap but for jQuery it just doesn't seem to work for me that way. I included a simple clickevent like

`$.('.homeButton').click(function() {
      console.log('test');
    });`

in the ngOnInit() function but it gives me a compiler error saying 

**Identifier expected.**

Comment: did you  `declare var $:any;` in your file ?

Comment: forgot about that. must have missed to read it. works like a charm +1 for the effort

Comment: To install the jquery typings, it looks like we have to use `typings install dt~jquery --save` now